# Emergency; inbox not loading

Tags: bug, status-completed

I was shown two notifications, but after a moment of loading image, nothing appears. Hot questions and all sites area load as expected.

Not browser-specific, same results on Opera, Firefox and Chromium.

Please help me check those updated questions before I forget!

**UPDATE**

I received a new notification, it appeared but all the old ones has been cleared! I've got questions on the SE network, how can I know where I've been updated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We made some emergency changes to the network on Sunday; this should resolve itself soon.

Comment: Ah~ thanks. I'll mark this solved when my inbox returns with it's old posts.